# cant get android sqlite select statement to work

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to select the items that have expired in my database but nothing is ever returned. I've tried the following:

```
select * from productTable where columnExpiration < date( currentDate)
```

All dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd

When that didn't work I tried:

```
Select* from productTable where columnExpiration < currentDate
```

Any suggestions?  This is really starting to drive me crazy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Try here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison), which has already been asked, and has a solution:

use Datetime() to format your dates before comparison.

Comment: But I've already tried several of the methods that worked for that poster such as the yyyymmdd format which IS NOT working for me.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'd really appreciate some help because datatime is not working either.  There has to be some other problem.  here is the exact code     String selectString = "SELECT * FROM "+ productTable+ " WHERE datetime("+columnExpiration+") < datetime("+currentDate+")" ;

Comment: Start by breaking the query down to a basic test that you can run by hand, to see that you're getting the result you need. then work your way up to the query your code will run... if that makes sense. (Sorry for slow response, I don't hang out here)