# sqlite date comparison

Tags: iphone, date, sqlite

I have column of type date time and values are getting stored in format 10-29-2011 08:25.

I would like to find out the rows only which are less then current date-time. What will be the condition for date comparison for current date and this date-time column field?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison

Comment: but how to compare with current date-time?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the datetime function

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mydate > datetime('now')
```

you can even make date operations

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mydate > datetime('now','-15 days')
```