# How can I get all data between two dates from sqlite database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

In my sqlite database there is a "*Date*" field, & its data type is varchar,

I want to get all data between two dates - how would I do this from a sqlite database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1976040/919545

Comment: show me any record of dates. which date formate you use in record?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite DateTime comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 NSString * sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM table WHERE (startdate <='%@') AND (enddate >='%@)",startdateString, enddateString];
```

OR

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE  datecol  BETWEEN '2012-02-08 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-10 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
2. time(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
3. datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
4. julianday(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
5. strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)

Use one of the above function to convert your string to date
More detail please refer: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: And after converting it to date, try this: SELECT data FROM myTable WHERE date BETWEEN date1 AND date2

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is here: [*Working with strings in SQLite*](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg08.htm).