# SQLite compare dates

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I have this SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT Geburtsdatum FROM Kunde
WHERE Geburtsdatum BETWEEN '1993-01-01' AND '2000-01-01'
```

but I get some weird results, like: 2.02.1990

'Geburtsdatum' is a DATE

Any suggestions or solutions?

my table-structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Kunde (
  Kunde_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
  Card INTEGER ,
  Vorname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  Nachname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  Ort VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  Strasse VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  Postleitzahl VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  Mail VARCHAR(255) ,
  Telefonnummer VARCHAR(255) ,
  Geburtsdatum DATE NOT NULL ,
  Beitrittsdatum DATE NOT NULL ,
  Geschlecht INTEGER NOT NULL ,
  Land VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Österreich' ,
  Bankname VARCHAR(255) ,
  Bankleitzahl VARCHAR(255) ,
  Kontonummer VARCHAR(255) ,
  GroupID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
  Besucher INTEGER ,
  Access BOOLEAN ,
  image BLOB NULL ,
  writeDate DATE ,
  drinkAbo BOOLEAN ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Kunde_ID) )
```

Comment: Can you show some samples on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Hang on a sec. From the documentation: "SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times." So it *can't* be a DATE - what is your column really?

Comment: it is a DATE.. in my creationscript, also my sqlite-manager show me a DATE-type

Comment: @juergend : in sql fiddle it works oO

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the documentation:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times.

So your column isn't exactly stored as a date. Reading further, we learn that columns specifed as `DATE` are actually stored as `NUMERIC` using affinity rule 5.

Going back up to section 1.2:

> REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.

Good. So let's try:

```
SELECT Geburtsdatum FROM Kunde
WHERE Geburtsdatum 
    BETWEEN julianday('1993-01-01') AND julianday('2000-01-01');
```

---

Oddly enough, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) seems to store `DATE`s as strings and the above doesn't work. In this case, the following should:

```
SELECT Geburtsdatum FROM Kunde
WHERE date(Geburtsdatum)
    BETWEEN date('1993-01-01') AND date('2000-01-01');
```

Additionally, in your case you seem to be getting some strange (read: localized) format returned. I wonder if it really is a string in your case too, just with a different format. You could try:

```
SELECT Geburtsdatum FROM Kunde
WHERE strftime('%d.%m.%Y', Geburtsdatum)
    BETWEEN date('1993-01-01') AND date('2000-01-01');
```

Comment: I don't compare strings.. I edited the question -> table structure.
When I convert 'Geburtsdatum' to DATE or DATETIME no result is shown.

If I only convert the 'Between-Values' the results are wrong.

Comment: Interesting, and wow dates are funny in SQLite. Check my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Someone had the same problem and got it resolved. (use datetime function before comparison)

See [SQLite DateTime comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison)

**Excerpt:**
Following the datetime function and having a string format as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss i achieved good results as follows

```
select * 
  from table_1 
  where mydate >= Datetime('2009-11-13 00:00:00') 
  and mydate <= Datetime('2009-11-15 00:00:00')
```

--EDIT--

You are basically comparing strings. Which is why the unexpected behavior. Convert to datetime using the function right before comparison and it should work.

Comment: it's a date, not a datetime and I tried this way & get also some weird results.

Comment: weird /wi(ə)rd/ "Suggesting something supernatural; uncanny"...
is a vague word. What exactly are you seeing? What does your values in the table look like?

Comment: e.g. I get a result like the date: '13.02.1990' and thats not between the year 1993 and 2000, right? :)

Comment: because you are comparing strings. Use the datetime function to convert to date and then compare.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to compare dates, you must store them in one of [SQLite's supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), such as a `JJJJ-MM-TT` string. Your dates are stored as strings in a localized date format which is not recognized by SQLite.

If the most significant field is not at the start of the string, string comparisons will not work for dates.
With the values currently in your table, you will not be able to do any comparisons.