# Select records newer than a specified date

Tags: android, sql, datetime, sqlite

I'm working with Sqlite on Android. Within a table I got a column of String value that stores a timestamp in UTC formatted like this "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". Now I want to compare that value against another timestamp that's in the same format. Let's say you want all recorders newer than "2013-01-01 00:00:00". But how to use this in a SELECT statement?

example:

- Table: human
- Column: (TEXT) name
- Column: (TEXT) bornOnUtc

And now select all humans born after 2013-01-01 00:00:00?

Comment: What about adding ` WHERE BornOnUTC > '2013-01-01 00:00:00'` to your rawQuery?

Comment: But that's just a string-comparison than and now really based on DateTime.

Comment: And **how does it differ** from your accepted answer? Can you define DateTime, as interpreted by SQLite? It's really a string or an integer (depending on how you defined the field) in SQLite...

Comment: Because I did not know that you can actually compare date-time stamps based on strings. I later found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091000/sqlite-compare-dates), plaining why string-comparison works. So your answer was correct too, but I can not accept a comment as the correct answer.

Comment: People should learn from posts on this website. Even though my question might have been very easy I still don't understand why people downvote it. It's not a stupid or silly one, just an easy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM human
WHERE bornOnUtc >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually this is just string-comparison but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091000/sqlite-compare-dates) is a good explanation why this works.

Comment: This works, too: SELECT * FROM human WHERE DATE(bornOnUtc) > DATE('2013-01-01 00:00:00');

Comment: @Matthias: Your method works but introduces **overhead** (i.e.: **worst performances**), because of the **2 conversions**

Comment: You are right. String comparison is the much better choice here.