# Android SQLite select between two dates

Tags: android, string, sqlite, date, compare

I store date as TEXT in my database in this format YYYY-MM-DD.
Each row has start date and final date.
I want to select the row that today date is between the start date and final date.
Today date is string and is in the same format as those ex.2014-07-29
I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date(todayDate) BETWEEN date(COLUMN_START_DATE) AND date(COLUMN_FINAL_DATE)
```

but it didn't work. I get 0 row.
I've also tried

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', todayDate) BETWEEN COLUMN_START_DATE AND COLUMN_FINAL_DATE
```

Still not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check [Compare Dates in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091000/sqlite-compare-dates)

Comment: @Apoorv I did and I followed, but I failed to notice that there must be single quote before and after the string in the application. I just noticed this after I checked it again, my bad. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the results:-

```
String selection = "from_duration<=Datetime('" + initial_date
            + "') AND to_duration>=Datetime('" + final_date + "')";
your_database.query(Table_Name,Columns_youwant, selection,
            null, null, null, null);
```