# Different results for a similar queries depends on format of date string in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, strftime

I have two tables in sqlite3:

```
sqlite> create table date_1 (date text);
sqlite> create table date_2 (date text);
```

Each table contains three rows with dates written in different formats:

```
sqlite> select * from date_1;
28.09.2015
28.08.2015
29.08.2015
sqlite> select * from date_2;
2015-09-28
2015-08-28
2015-08-29
```

My current date is:

```
sqlite> select date('now');
2015-09-29
```

Why do I have a different results for the next similar queries?

```
sqlite> select * from date_1 where date < strftime('%d.%m.%Y', 'now', '-1 day');
28.08.2015
sqlite> select * from date_2 where date < strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now', '-1 day');
2015-08-28
2015-08-29
```

Why first query don't returns '29.08.2015' too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite has no date type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). When you do `date < strftime(...)` you're doing a *string comparison*. The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format like `2015-08-28` will compare as dates when compared as strings. `28.08.2015` will not, it will weigh the day first, then the month, then the year.

`strftime` only understands a limited set of formats (see ["Time Strings"](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)) and `28.09.2015` isn't one of them. Either store all dates in ISO 8601 format, or follow [the answers to this question cover how to compare dates in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091000/sqlite-compare-dates).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think, it will be better to store date in ISO 8601 format and convert to different formats like dd.mm.yyyy in SQL queries with strftime() if it necessary for some reasons.