# How to generate all dates between two dates

Tags: sqlite, date, between

How can I retrieve all dates between '2015-10-02' to '2015-11-02' in SQLite? (String type)
Result will be like:

```
'2015-10-03'
'2015-10-04'
'2015-10-05'
...
'2015-11-01'
```

This is **not** a question about `SELECT * FROM myTable where myDate <= '2015-01-01' AND myDate >= '2015-01-31'`. This is **not** about selecting all *existing* records which have a field between two days. I just want to retrieve all possible date values between two dates. I want to use them to query the count of record by days.

```
Date             Count
'2015-01-01'      19
'2015-01-02'      10
'2015-01-03'      0
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite compare dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091000/sqlite-compare-dates)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812986/easiest-way-to-populate-a-temp-table-with-dates-between-and-including-2-date-par looks relevant, but I'm not up on possible dialect differences between SQL Server and SQLite.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is not possible without a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), which was introduced in SQLite 3.8.3:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS (
  VALUES('2015-10-03')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day')
  FROM dates
  WHERE date < '2015-11-01'
)
SELECT date FROM dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it regularly, it may be worth generating a table holding all the dates in the range that you need.

Using Bash in Linux and it's `date` command, it's easy to generate the dates and populate a table with them.

Assuming you have a "days" table with a "d" column:

```sh
d='2019-01-01'          # start date
end='2021-12-31'        # end date
while ! [[ $d > $end ]]; do
  echo $d
  d=$(date -d "$d + 1 day" +%F)
done \
| sqlite3 $Your_DB '.import /dev/stdin days'
```

Or as a (long) one-liner:

```sh
d='2019-01-01'; end='2021-12-31'; while ! [[ $d > $end ]]; do echo $d; d=$(date -d "$d + 1 day" +%F); done | sqlite3 $Your_DB '.import /dev/stdin days'
```