# How to join generated datetimes with data in SQLite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, left-join, recursive-query

I have a table with data from a sensor created like that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "aqi" (
  "time" datetime,
  "pm25" real,
  "pm10" real
);
```

When is sensor running, it sends data to a server (which it writes to a database) every second. But when the sensor is not running, there are "gaps" in data in the database like that (I've rewritten `time` column to a readable format and timezone `GMT+01`, leaving raw data in parentheses):

| time | pm25 | pm10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| `2021-12-28 18:44` (`1640713462`) | `9.19` | `9.27` |
| `2021-12-28 18:45` (`1640713522`) | `9.65` | `9.69` |
| **`2021-12-28 18:46`** (`1640713582`) | `9.68` | `9.76` |
| **`2021-12-29 10:17`** (`1640769421`) | `7.42` | `7.42` |
| `2021-12-29 10:18` (`1640769481`) | `7.94` | `7.98` |
| `2021-12-29 10:19` (`1640769541`) | `7.42` | `7.43` |
| ... | ... | ... |

---

I wanted to **create a query, that selects data from the last 24 hours**, outputting `pm25` and `pm10` as `NULL` if there aren't data in the table for the current time. So the table above would look like that:

| time | pm25 | pm10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| `2021-12-28 18:44` (`1640713462`) | `9.19` | `9.27` |
| `2021-12-28 18:45` (`1640713522`) | `9.65` | `9.69` |
| `2021-12-28 18:46` (`1640713582`) | `9.68` | `9.76` |
| **`2021-12-28 18:47`** (`1640713642`) | **`NULL`** | **`NULL`** |
| **`2021-12-28 18:48`** (`1640713702`) | **`NULL`** | **`NULL`** |
| **`2021-12-28 18:49`** (`1640713762`) | **`NULL`** | **`NULL`** |
| ... | ... | ... |
| **`2021-12-29 10:14`** (`1640769262`) | **`NULL`** | **`NULL`** |
| **`2021-12-29 10:15`** (`1640769322`) | **`NULL`** | **`NULL`** |
| **`2021-12-29 10:16`** (`1640769382`) | **`NULL`** | **`NULL`** |
| `2021-12-29 10:17` (`1640769421`) | `7.42` | `7.42` |
| `2021-12-29 10:18` (`1640769481`) | `7.94` | `7.98` |
| `2021-12-29 10:19` (`1640769541`) | `7.42` | `7.43` |
| ... | ... | ... |

<sub><sup>I don't mind if the seconds would be different because of the generation of time...</sup></sub>

---

I tried generating `time` for the last 24 hours using code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987070 and that works, as I wanted:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE dates(generated_time) AS (
  VALUES(datetime('now', '-1 minute', 'localtime'))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT datetime(generated_time, '-1 minute')
  FROM dates
  LIMIT 1440
)
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime(generated_time)) AS time
FROM dates;
```

But I don't know how to add (`JOIN`) data from the sensor (columns `pm25`, `pm10`) to query above... I tried something, but it outputs 0 rows:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE dates(generated_time) AS (
  VALUES(datetime('now', '-1 minute', 'localtime'))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT datetime(generated_time, '-1 minute')
  FROM dates
  LIMIT 1440
)
SELECT
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime(generated_time)) AS generated_time,
    pm25, 
    pm10
FROM
    dates
    INNER JOIN aqi ON generated_time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime(aqi.time));
```

Probably it's something really obvious, that I'm missing, but I have no idea :/

---

**EDIT:**
As [@DrummerMann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17851130/drummermann) pointed out, it works with `LEFT JOIN`, but it takes around one whole minute to execute the query (in the database is around 14 000 values):

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(time) AS (
  VALUES(datetime('now', '-1 minute', 'localtime'))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT datetime(time, '-1 minute')
  FROM dates
  LIMIT 1440
)
SELECT
    dates.time,
    aqi.pm25, 
    aqi.pm10
FROM
    dates
    LEFT JOIN aqi ON strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime(dates.time)) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime(aqi.time, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'))
    ORDER BY dates.time;
```

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Have you checked out `LEFT JOIN`? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: I find out, that I forgot to add `'unixepoch', 'localtime'` to `datetime` conversion, so I edited my question with working `LEFT JOIN` code, but it takes one whole minute to execute the query...

Comment: move `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime(dates.time))` to cte. Using a precomputed value in the ON clause should be a bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version of the cte, which uses integer unix timestamps where the seconds are stripped off and there are no functions in the ON clause of the join:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(generated_time) AS (
  SELECT strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 minute', 'localtime') / 60 * 60
  UNION ALL
  SELECT generated_time - 60
  FROM dates
  LIMIT 1440
)
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', d.generated_time, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS generated_time,
       a.pm25, 
       a.pm10
FROM dates d LEFT JOIN aqi a
ON d.generated_time = a.time / 60 * 60;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but second line of query should look like this `SELECT strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 minute') / 60 * 60`, because with the `'localtime'` option `time` will be shifted in output... Now it takes about 3.5 second for execution, which is really good improvement :)

Comment: @BelKed I use the `'localtime'` modifier because you have it in your code and I assumed that the timestamps in your table are localized.

Comment: Oh, I see... I have in the table UTC unix timestamp, so it needs conversion to `'localtime'`, but in your answer you use `a.time` in last line without conversion to `'localtime'`, so that's probably the cause of time shift...