# R sqldf not being selective in date range criteria

Tags: r, date, sqldf

I am trying to select rows with a date value less than a value. It doesn't seem to be working as I am getting all date values, not just those less than a value.

Here's the df structure:

```
str(sawdf)
'data.frame':   83597 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ actiondate       : Date, format: "2016-05-08" "2016-05-08" "2016-05-09" ...
```

And here's some sample data:

```
head(sawdf)
  actiondate 
2016-05-14
2016-05-15  
2016-05-16 
2016-05-17 
2016-05-18
```

And here is my sql:

```
sqldf("select distinct actiondate from sawdf where actiondate < '2016-05-18'")
```

And here's some of the results:

```
...
6  2016-05-13
7  2016-05-14
8  2016-05-15
9  2016-05-16
10 2016-05-17
11 2016-05-18
12 2016-05-19
```

As you can see data beyond 2016-05-18 are being selected.

I've tried several approaches but am getting the same results.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing the backend being used is SQLite, which doesn't have a native date type (as SQL Server does). You may need to be more explicit in your query -- see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091000/sqlite-compare-dates) for some ideas.

Comment: Not sure of the backend. Thanks for pointing me to them but I think my question needs an R solution.

Comment: nrussell is correct. `sqldf` uses `SQLite` on the back-end by default. An R solution would be something like `unique(sawdf[sawdf$actiondate < as.Date("2016-05-18"), ])`.

Answer (score 1):

**1) sqlite** Assuming you are using the default SQLite backend, SQLite does not have a date type so the dates are transferred to SQLite as the number of days since the UNIX Epoch. That is on the SQLite side `actiondate` is a column of numbers.   (If `x` were a `"Date"` class R variable then `as.numeric(x)` gives the number(s) that is/are transferred to SQLite.)  We need to compare these numbers to an appropriate number, not to a character string.  This would work as it also converts the comparison date in the same way (i.e. it replaces `$date0` with 16939 which is the number of days since the UNIX Epoch represented by that date):

```
library(sqldf)

date0 <- as.Date("2016-05-18")
fn$sqldf("select distinct actiondate from sawdf where actiondate < $date0")
```

There is more information on date processing in sqldf with SQLite on the sqldf home page on github: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

**1a)** This would also work since all dates get transferred in the same way:

```
library(sqldf)

Date0 <- data.frame(date0 = as.Date("2016-05-18"))
sqldf("select distinct actiondate from sawdf where actiondate < (select date0 from Date0)")
```

**1b)** Although it is a bit messy, rather than convert the comparison date to numeric one could convert the actiondate column to character using an SQLite builtin function:

```
sqldf("select distinct actiondate from sawdf 
       where strftime('%Y-%m-%d', actiondate * 3600 * 24, 'unixepoch') < '2016-05-18'")
```

**2) H2**  Alternately use the H2 backend which does have a date type. In that case the code in the question does work.  Install RH2 (which includes H2) and also make sure you have java installed on your machine.  Then:

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select distinct actiondate from sawdf where actiondate < '2016-05-18'")
```

**Note:** The input we assumed, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "actiondate
2016-05-14
2016-05-15  
2016-05-16 
2016-05-17 
2016-05-18"
sawdf <- read.csv(text = Lines)
sawdf$actiondate <- as.Date(sawdf$actiondate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but @Gregor has a great solution.  If you are bound and determined to use SQL though, you can first convert the date into a character (since SQLite doesn't have a date type):

```
sawdf <- data.frame(actiondate = as.Date(c("2016-05-14", "2016-05-15", "2016-05-30")))
sawdf$actiondate <- as.character(sawdf$actiondate)
str(sawdf)

sqldf("select actionDate 
  from sawdf where substr(actionDate,1,4)||substr(actionDate,6,2)||substr(actionDate,9,2) < '20160520'")

  actiondate
1 2016-05-14
2 2016-05-15
```