# Add numbers of day to Date SqLite

Tags: sqlite

I need add +1 Day, to a selectec Date, in Slq the sintax is: `SELECT DATEADD(day,+1, period.DateEnd)` and it works, but in sqLite es different.

I try with this, but it doesn't work, for example, the DateEnd = '31/12/2012', I need add 1 day to that date, te resulset should be: DateEnd = '01/01/2013'

```
  SELECT date('period2.DateEnd', '+1 day') as date 
  FROM Period as period2 
  WHERE period2.c_Pk_CodPeriod = '1012'
```

Comment: Use this link, it will tell you about the Addition / Subtraction of days in date, conversion and comparison. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43892359/1252158

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Currently you've got `period2.DateEnd` as a *string*. I suspect you want:

```
SELECT date(period2.DateEnd, '+1 day') as date 
FROM Period as period2 
WHERE period2.c_Pk_CodPeriod = '1012'
```