# how to compare datetime in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have stored entrytime in "2012-09-12_12:45" format in SQLite table, now I have to find all entries between 08:00 to 19:00. Please suggest me query to find such kind of entries.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE substr(MyColumn, 12, 5) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '19:00'
```