# Sqlite - check if today is between 2 dates

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table that was defined like this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyExercises (ID INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR, VIDEONAME VARCHAR, IMAGENAME VARCHAR, VALIDFROM SMALLDATETIME, VALIDTO SMALLDATETIME, NUMOFREPS INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(ID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO));");
```

and i want to check if today is between VALIDFROM  and VALIDTO.

When i insert the data to the table the dates look like this e.g.: 4/7/2013 12:00:00 AM ,4/27/2013 12:00:00 AM

```
INSERT INTO MyExercises VALUES (1,'blalbla','blabla', 'ex1.3gp', 'ex1.jpg', '4/7/2013 12:00:00 AM', '4/27/2013 12:00:00 AM' ,5)
```

but this query:

```
"SELECT NAME FROM MyExercises WHERE date('now') BETWEEN VALIDFROM AND VALIDTO"
```

doesn't return anything, even though today is between the dates from and to..

====================================================================

Solved it by changing all data to YYYY-MM-DD format

Thanks guys!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7316756/1329126

Comment: SELECT NAME FROM MyExercises WHERE date('now') BETWEEN strftime('%s', VALIDFROM) AND strftime('%s', VALIDTO)

Comment: Have u logged anything? do u know that date('now') function returns the current time. There may be timezone problem. check that

Comment: date('now') returns 2013-04-20

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
> 1.Insert two date(from,to)
> 2.Get all date between "from" and "to" date and store into arraylist or container //this step you may ignore also
> 3.check condition !from_Date.after(to_Date)
```

[example](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122972/android-emulator-cannot-find-tables-in-database)

Comment: As a general rule, never do something in code, that can be done in the database directly. Why? Because the database can optimize a lot of stuff for you, and since you're working with a mobile application, there are limitations on your resources. If you do your `select` in database and only fetch the data that you actually need, you're better off with that. Don't create a lot of unnecessary objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
db.query("MyExercises", null, TODAY + "BETWEEN ? AND ?", new String[] {
          VALIDFROM + " 00:00:00", VALIDTO+ " 23:59:59" }, null, null, null, null);
```

Here TODAY is today's date