# Select Where date is greater than or equal to today in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have dates stored in my Database in a `dd/mm/yyyy` format and I am looking to only show items where the date is equal to or great than today.

I have tried WHERE `date(fixtures.date) >= date('now')` but I got no results.

Below is my query, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
SELECT fixtures.id, 
       fixtures.team_1_id, 
       fixtures.team_2_id, 
       fixtures.date, 
       fixtures.time, 
       fixtures.pitch, 
       teams.team_name, 
       teams_1.team_name AS awayTeam, 
       leagues.league_name 
FROM   fixtures 
       INNER JOIN teams 
               ON fixtures.team_1_id = teams.id 
       INNER JOIN teams AS teams_1 
               ON fixtures.team_2_id = teams_1.id 
       INNER JOIN teams_vs_leagues 
               ON teams.id = teams_vs_leagues.team_id 
       INNER JOIN leagues 
               ON teams_vs_leagues.league_id = leagues.id 
WHERE  date(fixtures.date) >= date('now') 
ORDER  BY fixtures.date DESC
```

Comment: `I have dates stored in my Database in a dd/mm/yyyy format` why not a normal UNIX timestamp? it is much easier to do any processing with it

Comment: you are not suppose to use `date` as column name, as its a keyword for `Sqlite`.. [visit - read first line](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Answer (score 14):

Why do you say your dates are store in dd/mm/yyyy format? According to [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> **1.2 Date and Time Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> 1. TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> 2. REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> 3. INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Basically this query won't work

```
select 1 where '01-08-2016' >= date('now')
```

but this will

```
select 1 where '2016-08-01'>= date('now')
```

So can you verify if your date `fixtures.date` is format as 'yyyy-MM-dd' otherwise your query won't work. Additionally remember to use `date('now', 'localtime')` to get your local time.

If your date is well formated you can try to do something like

```
SELECT fixtures.id
FROM   fixtures
WHERE  fixtures.date >= date('now')
```

if you do get results with this, then the joins are not matching any row.

For further information you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507581/3950497)