# How can I query a date from a datetime object in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, date, datetime, select, syntax-error

Here is my attempt:

`rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from geninfo where DeviceTag='" + deviceTag + "' and timestamp='date('"+fromYear + "-" +fromMonth + "-" + fromDay + "')';");`

It will look similar to this:

```
select * from geninfo where timestamp='date('2013-07-08')';
```

The error is `(near "2013": syntax error)`

The value stored is "2013-07-08 09:08:51"

I want to select all the data of a certain day. Also, would it be easier to just store another column as a date object?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison) answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must not surround the `date` function with single quotes, which are string delimiters.
   What you have in the SQL statement is the string `date(`, the numbers `2013`, `07`, and `08`, which are subtracted from each other, and the string `)`.
2. The function `date` converts the string `2013-07-08` into the string `2013-07-08`.
   Comparing that to the string `2013-07-08 09:08:51` will fail.
   You want to strip the time from the string that has the time fields:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM geninfo
   WHERE DeviceTag = ?
     AND date(timestamp) = '2013-07-08'
   ```