# How to fix SQLite3::SQLException: near "to": syntax error: SELECT "".* FROM "" WHERE ""."" = ? AND (to < '[Time.now]') LIMIT ? OFFSET?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, syntax-error

I am developing a Rails application and using SQLite3 as my database server. I am having an issue querying `conferences` that have a `to` `date_time` that is less than `Time.now`. Here is the exact statement in my controller:

```
@conferences = @conferences.where("to < ?", Time.now)
```

Where `@conferences` is defined beforehand in my controller as

```
@conferences = @conferences.where("to < ?", Time.now)
```

I get the following error message:

> SQLite3::SQLException: near "to": syntax error: SELECT 
>   "conferences".* FROM "conferences" WHERE "conferences"."country_id" =
>   ? AND (to < '2019-08-16 22:45:57.891117') LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

I have tried setting up and reading more about `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, but that didn't work probably because I don'thave a good understanding of what they do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite DateTime comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
@conferences = @conferences.where("\"to\" < ?", Time.now)
```

`to` is a reserved keyword in SQL. If you want to use it as a column name it has to be escaped with double quotes to mark it as an identifier instead.