# Sqlite datetime comparison with a unix timestamp

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, unix-timestamp

The Sqlite documentation [states](https://sqlite.org/quirks.html):

> SQLite has no DATETIME datatype. Instead, dates and times can be stored in any of these ways:
>
> - As a TEXT string in the ISO-8601 format. Example: '2018-04-02 12:13:46'.
> - As an INTEGER number of seconds since 1970 (also known as "unix time").
>   ...

so I decided to use an `INTEGER` unix timestamp:

```
import sqlite3, time
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE data(datetime INTEGER, t TEXT);")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO data VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'hello')")
```

Why does the following query return no result?

```
ts = int(time.time()) + 31*24*3600  # unix timestamp 1 month in the future
print(list(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE datetime <= ?", (ts, ))))
```

**More generally, how to do a `SELECT` query with a comparison with a unix timestamp with Sqlite?**

---

PS:

- I have already read [SQLite DateTime comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison) and similar questions, which offer other comparison methods, but here I'd like to precisely discuss why this unix timestamp comparison does not work.
- For performance reasons, I'd like to:

  - do a query that compares *integers* (which is super fast if many rows): `WHERE datetime <= unix_timestamp`,
  - avoid to convert `unix_timestamp` into string, and then compare `datetime` to this string (I guess it'll be far slower)

Comment: I dont know if this will be helpful but when I use unix time in miliseconds, as an int then it will make an overflow, long is better.

Comment: @mama Does Sqlite use unix timestamps in milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: python does use seconds as default. idk about sqlite, but normally default is milliseconds

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Why? The row is inserted with current timestamp. So querying with `datetime <= timestamp_1_month_in_the_future` should work.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus IIRC, it also contains the HH:MM:SS and possibly milliseconds? Do you have a source about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when inserting new rows.
This means that in your column the values are not stored as unix timestamps becuase `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the current date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

You can transform the unix timestamp to datetime in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` with the function `datetime()` and the `unixepoch` modifier:

```
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE datetime <= datetime(?, 'unixepoch')", (ts, ))
```

If your unix timestamp contains milliseconds you must strip them off:

```
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE datetime <= datetime(? / 1000, 'unixepoch')", (ts, ))
```

Or, you can transform the string datetime in the column `datetime` to a unix timestamp with the function `strftime()`:

```
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE strftime('%s', datetime) + 0 <= ?", (ts, ))
```

If you want to store integer values in the column, use `strftime()` like this:

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES (strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 0, 'hello')
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas. For performance reasons, I'd like to do a query that compares *integers* (which is super fast if many rows): `WHERE datetime <= unix_timestamp`,
and avoid to convert `unix_timestamp` into string, and then compare datetime to this string (I guess it'll be far slower?). What do you think?

Comment: *CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the current date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss* oh this might be the reason, do you have a source/link for this, for future reference? Also, how could I get the current timestamp as unix timetamp instead of string?

Comment: Thanks @forpas! PS: Why the `+ 0`?

Comment: strftime() returns a string and  +0 does an implicit conversion to an integer.