# SQL query not returning expected results in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am facing an issue with a SQL query in SQLite, and I can't figure out why it's not returning the expected results.

This is the table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Giohang 
(
    magh INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    masp INTEGER REFERENCES Sanpham (masp),
    makh TEXT REFERENCES Khachhang (makh),
    mahang INTEGER REFERENCES Hangsp (mahang),
    tongtien INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ngay DATE,
    soluong INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Sample data:

| magh | masp | makh | mahang | tongtien | ngay | soluong |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 1 | 2000 | 2023/11/20 11:43:01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | a | 1 | 2200 | 2023/11/20 11:43:01 | 1 |

And here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(tongtien) AS doanhthu 
FROM Giohang 
WHERE ngay >= '2023/11/01' AND ngay <= '2023/11/20';
```

I expect this query to return the total value of the `tongtien` column from November 1 to November 20, 2023. However, it returns `NULL` without any errors. Could you please help me identify why?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) both apply to this question.

Comment: Making the link no longer clickable does not change anything. Please read the two links I provided to you, and then [edit] your post to properly include the relevant database information, sample data, expected output, and the output you're getting instead.

Comment: You can find helpful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison) about date comparison in SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngay >= '2023/11/01' AND ngay <= '2023/11/20'` is the equivalent of `ngay >= '2023/11/01 00:00:00' AND ngay <= '2023/11/20 00:00:00';`

You need to specify time when comparing datetimes :

```
SELECT SUM(tongtien) AS doanhthu 
FROM Giohang 
WHERE ngay >= '2023/11/01 00:00:00' AND ngay <= '2023/11/20 23:59:59';
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(tongtien) AS doanhthu 
FROM Giohang 
WHERE ngay >= '2023/11/01' AND ngay < '2023/11/21';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NSHcRoH_)

Answer (score 0):

This search gets all the data between two month where the year value is given

```
 ElseIf gvSearchType = "MoRangeYr" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth >= $gvFromMonth AND txSearchMonth <= $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth BETWEEN $gvFromMonth AND $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvToMonth", gvToMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
```

Then the data is shown in a DataGridView with this code

```
                Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'dgvTX.DataSource = rdr
                'Statement Above is when DB is bound to dgvTX
                '============================================

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("TID")))
                    strDate = rdr("txSortDate").ToString 'txSearchMonth '
                    strTxType = rdr("txType").ToString
                    strAmt = CDec(rdr("txAmount"))
                    strCKNum = rdr("txCKNum").ToString
                    strDesc = rdr("txDesc").ToString
                    strBal = CDec(rdr("txBalance"))
                    dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    'dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"'Adds the $ sign and commas
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(intID, strDate, strTxType, strAmt, strCKNum, strDesc, strBal, emptyStr)

                    rowCount = rowCount + 1

                End While

                dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                dgvTX.Sort(dgvTX.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)
            End Using
```